# I want to link two variables by ref so as when I update one variable the other updates also

Tags: c#

I want to assign one variable to another by reference so as when one variable updates so does the other.

I have a series of variables that I need to update based on something that a piece of hardware I am connected to is doing.  I have set up an object array and am assigning each of my variables to an index in the object array.  It is the object array that gets updated but when this happens I want the property setter for my original variable to fire so as I can do something.  The reason for the object array is so as I can iterate through it in a loop and because my original variables can be of different types.  I have shown an overly simplified version of what I am trying to do below, I hope it makes sense.

Edit: Just to note that the items in the testVars array are being updated elsewhere, I have just shown a simplified version of what I am trying to do below.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool _test0 = false;
    private int _test1 = 0;

    public object[] testVars = new object[2];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testVars[0] = test0;
        testVars[1] = test1;
    }

    public bool test0
    {
        get
        {
            return _test0;
        }
        set
        {
            _test0 = value;
            UpdateTest0();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateTest0()
    {
        bool NewTest0 = _test0;
    }

    public int test1
    {
        get
        {
            return _test1;
        }
        set
        {
            _test1 = value;
            UpdateTest1();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateTest1()
    {
        int NewTest1 = _test1;
    }
}
```

One solution I thought might work for me was to use pointers but because the variable declaration and pointer creation must be in different scope in my application this will not work.  Also everything I have read on forums has suggested that pointers should not be used.

@ Michael Ceber, many thanks for the prompt response.  I think I understand what you mean and have updated my example code accordingly but it still does not behave as I want.  My updated code is as follows

namespace VariableLinks
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool _test0 = false;
        private int _test1 = 0;

```
    public ObjectX[] testVars = new ObjectX[2];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testVars[0] = new ObjectX();
        testVars[0].val = test0;
        testVars[1] = new ObjectX();
        testVars[1].val = test1;
    }

    public bool test0
    {
        get
        {
            return _test0;
        }
        set
        {
            _test0 = value;
            UpdateTest0();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateTest0()
    {
        bool NewTest0 = _test0;
    }

    public int test1
    {
        get
        {
            return _test1;
        }
        set
        {
            _test1 = value;
            UpdateTest1();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateTest1()
    {
        int NewTest1 = _test1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testVars[0].val = true;
    }
}

public class ObjectX : object
{
    public object val = new object();
}
```

}

Now when my button click event fires and updates testVars[0].val I expect the setter for test0 to fire but it doesn't.  I assume I have misunderstood what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

If you store objects or reference types to objects in your array, i.e not value types like int, bool etc, which contain the values, then this will help.

e.g if your object 'objectx' has a property called value then objectx.value can store such a value.

Then you can set any variables you like to this objectx and whenever you update the value of objectx.value all variables will pickup the change, as they are all pointing to the same object...

So in your example

testVars[0] = test0;
testVars[1] = test1;

this would become

testVars[0].value = test0;
testVars[1].value = test1;

maybe to achieve this

public object[] testVars = new object[2];

should become

public ObjectX[] testVars = new ObjectX[2];

and add the single public property 'value' to this ObjectX class...

Hope that makes sense!